# Nexus 4, Sherlock Action Bar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

we have a problem with styling tabs in Sherlock. The problem can be seen on this picture(an unfinished orange line), which is captured from Nexus 4 :

[image]
We have tested this on some other devices with lower resolution, but it's ok.

Thx for any reply

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do with the resolution of the drawables you are using. 
Do you have an item with higher resolution for the tab background in the hdpi/xhdpi folders?